# Add local storage to todo list project

Tags: javascript, object, dom, local-storage, es6-modules

I would like to add local storage to my todo list but cannot seem to figure out how to integrate it in my project I have managed to save the data but can't seem to save it to the webpage (when refreshing the displayed projects and tasks disappear.)

dom.js

```js
const projectList = document.querySelector(".project-list")
const projectForm = document.querySelector(".project-form")
const projectValue = projectForm.querySelector("input[name='add-project']")
const main = document.querySelector(".main-container")
const taskList = document.createElement("div")
taskList.classList = "task-list"


const createTask = () => {
    const taskTitle = document.getElementById("task-title").value
    const taskDuedate = document.getElementById("due-date").value
    const taskPriority = document.getElementById("task-priority").value
    const newTask = taskFactory(taskTitle,
        taskDuedate, taskPriority)
    return newTask
}

const createProject = () => {
    const projectInput = document.getElementById("project").value
    const newProject = projectFactory(projectInput)
    return newProject
}

const updateUI = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newProject = createProject()
    /* Iterate through each project in array and check if current project title is equal to new projects title if not create new project */
    const projectExists = PM.projects.some((project) => project.title === newProject.title)
    if (!projectExists) {
        PM.addProject(newProject)
        projectList.textContent = ""
        PM.projects.forEach((project) => {
            // Create projects
            const projectContainer = document.createElement("div")
            const projectDiv = document.createElement("h3")
            const addTaskBtn = document.createElement("button")
            const deleteProjectBtn = document.createElement("button")

            projectDiv.textContent = `Project: ${project.title}`
            projectDiv.setAttribute("project-index", project.id)

            projectDiv.className = "project-div"
            projectContainer.className = "project-container"

            addTaskBtn.className = "add-project-task"
            addTaskBtn.textContent = "Add Task"
            deleteProjectBtn.textContent = "Delete"
            deleteProjectBtn.className = "delete-project"
            projectDiv.append(deleteProjectBtn)
            projectContainer.append(projectDiv)
            projectList.append(projectContainer)
            projectContainer.append(addTaskBtn, deleteProjectBtn)

            //Add local storage
            localStorage.setItem("PM.projects", JSON.stringify(PM.projects));
            const retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("PM.projects");
            console.log("retrievedObject: ", JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

            addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault()
                // Set variable to createTask function (taskFactory)
                const newTask = createTask()
                // Add new task to current project
                project.addTask(newTask)
                // Create elements to display logic
                const taskDiv = document.createElement("div")
                const projectTask = document.createElement("project")
                const taskTitle = document.createElement("task")
                const taskDate = document.createElement("due-date")
                const taskPriority = document.createElement("priority")
                const deleteTaskBtn = document.createElement("button")
                deleteTaskBtn.textContent = "✕"

                projectTask.textContent = `Project: ${project.title}`
                taskTitle.textContent = `Task: ${newTask.title}`
                taskDate.textContent = `Due-date: ${newTask.dueDate}`
                taskPriority.textContent = `Priority: ${newTask.priority}`

                projectTask.className = "project-task"
                taskDiv.className = "task-div"
                taskDiv.setAttribute("task-div", newTask.id)
                taskTitle.className = "task-title"
                taskDate.className = "task-due-date"
                taskPriority.className = "task-priority"
                deleteTaskBtn.className = "delete-task-btn"

                taskDiv.append(deleteTaskBtn, projectTask, taskTitle, taskDate, taskPriority)

                const taskContainer = document.createElement("div")
                taskContainer.classList = "task-container"
                taskContainer.append(taskDiv)

                taskList.append(taskDiv)

                // Edit task elements
                const newForm = document.createElement("form")
                const newInput = document.createElement("input")
                const newTaskLabel = document.createElement("label")
                const editTaskBtn = document.createElement("button")
                const editPriorityBtn = document.createElement("button")
                const editDueDate = document.createElement("button")
                const newPriority = document.createElement("select")
                const newDueDate = document.createElement("input")

                editTaskBtn.textContent = "Edit task"
                editTaskBtn.className = "edit-task-btn"
                editPriorityBtn.textContent = "Edit Priority"
                editDueDate.textContent = "Edit Due date"
                editDueDate.className = "edit-due-date-btn"
                editPriorityBtn.className = "edit-priority-btn"
                newInput.id = "new-task-input"

                // Edit current task 
                taskTitle.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    newInput.type = "text"
                    newInput.name = "new-task-input"
                    newTaskLabel.setAttribute("for", "updated-task")
                    newTaskLabel.textContent = "Update task: "
                    newTaskLabel.append(newInput)
                    newForm.append(newTaskLabel)
                    taskDiv.append(newForm, editTaskBtn)
                })

                editTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    project.updateTask(newTask.id, { title: `${newInput.value}` })
                    taskTitle.textContent = `Task: ${newInput.value}`
                    newTaskLabel.remove()
                    newInput.remove()
                    editTaskBtn.remove()
                })

                taskPriority.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    const newPriorityLow = document.createElement("option");
                    const newPriorityMedium = document.createElement("option");
                    const newPriorityHigh = document.createElement("option");
                    newPriorityLow.text = "Low"
                    newPriorityMedium.text = "Medium"
                    newPriorityHigh.text = "High"
                    newPriority.textContent = "New Priority: "
                    newPriority.className = "new-priority"
                    newPriority.append(newPriorityLow, newPriorityMedium, newPriorityHigh)
                    taskDiv.append(newPriority, editPriorityBtn)
                })

                editPriorityBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    project.updateTask(newTask.id, { priority: `${newPriority.value}` })
                    taskPriority.textContent = `Priority: ${newPriority.value}`
                    newPriority.remove()
                    editPriorityBtn.remove()
                })

                taskDate.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    newDueDate.setAttribute("type", "date")
                    newDueDate.className = "new-due-date"
                    taskDiv.append(newDueDate, editDueDate)
                })

                editDueDate.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    project.updateTask(newTask.id, { dueDate: `${newDueDate.value}` })
                    taskDate.textContent = `Due-date ${newDueDate.value}`
                    newDueDate.remove()
                    editDueDate.remove()
                })
                // Remove single task
                deleteTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    project.deleteTask(newTask)
                    taskDiv.remove()
                })
                main.append(taskList)
            })
            // Delete project + tasks
            deleteProjectBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault()
                PM.deleteProject(project)
                projectDiv.remove()
                addTaskBtn.remove()
                deleteProjectBtn.remove()
                // Select all task divs
                const projectTasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task-div");
                // Loop through all task divs in current project and remove
                for (let i = 0; i < projectTasks.length; i += 1) {
                    // If current project task includes project title remove project tasks
                    if (projectTasks[i].textContent.includes(project.title)) {
                        projectTasks[i].remove();
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

projectValue.addEventListener("click", updateUI);
```

project.js

```js
// Project Manager object
const PM = {
    projects: [],
    addProject(project) {
        this.projects.push(project)
    },
    deleteProject(project) {
        const projectIndex = this.projects.indexOf(project)
        if (projectIndex !== -1) {
            this.projects.splice(projectIndex, 1)
            return true
        }
        return false
    },
    updateProject(projectId, newTitle) {
        // Iterate through projects array
        for (let i = 0; i < this.projects.length; i += 1) {
            // Check current iteration project id to project id
            if (this.projects[i].id === projectId) {
                // If title hasnt changed return false
                if (this.projects[i].title === newTitle) return false
                // Else return project title with new title
                this.projects[i].title = newTitle
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    },
}

const projectFactory = (title) => ({
    title,
    tasks: [],
    id: uuidv4(),
    addTask(task) {
        this.tasks.push(task)
    },
    deleteTask(task) {
        const taskIndex = this.tasks.indexOf(task)
        if (taskIndex !== -1) {
            this.tasks.splice(taskIndex, 1)
            return true
        }
        return false
    },
    updateTask(taskId, data) {
        Object.assign(this.tasks.find(el => el.id === taskId), data)
    }
})
```

task.js

```js
const taskFactory = (title, dueDate, priority) => ({ title, dueDate, priority, id: uuidv4(), })

const createTask = (title, dueDate, priority) => {
    const task = taskFactory(title, dueDate, priority)
    return task
}
```

I have tried following other StackOverflow questions using in my updateUI function :

```js
    localStorage.setItem("PM.projects", JSON.stringify(PM.projects));
    const retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("PM.projects");
    console.log("retrievedObject: ", JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

But that manages to only save the data to local storage i'd like to also save it to the webpage/display (projects and tasks).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this only saves the data to local storage I'd like to save it to the web page". If you want to display data from local storage you need to retrieve the data from local storage and do something with it. Like when you load the page get the local storage data and use that as the initial data for rendering.

Comment: "*But that manages to only save the data to local storage*" If `localStorage.getItem()` *saves* data to local storage, you've got a lot of bigger issues to understand first; namely why your user agent implements the opposite logic of what the specification requires.

Comment: No idea what "namely why your user agent implements the opposite logic of what the specification requires." even means @esqew.

Comment: Yes that what I'm trying to do display the data from local storage. I have looked into window.addEventListener to display and retrieve the data when it loads but can't get it to work. @DaveNewton

Comment: @DataMoshing `getItem` should do *just* that - *get* the value of the key you provide. If your browser is truly updating information as a direct result of that discrete call (as you imply with your statement "*that manages to only save the data to local storage*"), there is a huge issue with your browser, because that's the opposite of what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, I have worded it wrong my apologies. I think I will just move on from this project, I have been spinning my wheels for quite a while trying to get this to work. Thanks for the response. @esqew

Comment: … You’re not describing the issue you’re having with retrieving the data and displaying it. If you can save the data you can retrieve it and show it.

Comment: When I save the data it's there when I go to application in the browser it has the projects saved in the local storage. It is my projects and my tasks that are added and shown on the user interface that get cleared once I refresh the webpage. I would like to have the projects and tasks shown on load from the local storage instead of disappearing. @DaveNewton

Comment: Right; I’m asking why you can’t do that. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to connect the local storage to the user interface. An example I've seen is something along the lines of h2.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("value") where they set the value of getItem to the h2. That is the issue setting an HTML element to display the local storage. @DaveNewton

Comment: Load the data and parse it. Loop over the data creating the appropriate DOM elements for each.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I appreciate you for taking the time out to respond. @DaveNewton